# with statement seems to not close file correctly (a subprocess also uses the file)

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, text-files, with-statement

A step that I am trying to achieve in my program (which is another auto grader, but in python) is to write a temporary txt file containing the output of an outside program (students' homework). I am able to successfully write the txt file using a `with` statement, but I am unable to then remove the file. To remove the txt file, I am using `os.remove(file.txt)` but I keep getting the following error:

> PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'file.txt'

I am assuming that this is because the `with` statement is not closing the txt file correctly. In an attempt to forcibly close the file, I have tried to add `.close()` but I know that that is a bit redundant. I am also considering that it could be the `subprocess.Popen()` line but I have used this in other programs and I haven't had issues with it when I have tried to manipulate the same file (i.e. writing a txt file, then later reading it). But in order to test this, I tried to use `kill()` but I'm having trouble getting that to work correctly.

If anyone can give me insight as to what is going wrong and hint at what I need to do, I'd appreciate it!

```
hw_file = f"{submissions_folder}\\TaylorDavisOnTime.java" # example of naming style for student assignments
student_txt_file =  hw_file.replace(f"{submissions_folder}\\", f"{submissions_folder}\\output\\").replace(".java", "Output.txt")

with open(student_txt_file, "w") as file:
    output = subprocess.Popen(["java", hw_file], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=file, text=True)
    for input in input_values:
        output.stdin.write(input[0])
        output.stdin.write(str(input[1]))
        output.stdin.write(str(input[2]))  
    output.stdin.flush()
    output.stdin.close() 
    # output.kill() # still playing with this
    remove = True 
    file.close() # redundant, but does nothing

if remove: 
    os.remove(student_txt_file)
```

Comment: Looks like you could simplify this by using the `tempfile` module.

Comment: try `output.wait() `

Comment: You don't need `flush()`. Closing a file flushes it automatically.

Comment: So what happens if you properly terminate the subprocess (who is *also* using the file, whether or not you have closed it) before trying to remove the file?

Comment: Looks like the java process is still running, and it still has that file open.

Comment: Another issue. If the Java program expects each input on its own line, you'll need to append `'\n'` to each input.

Comment: @Barmar I had forget to include the input values in my sample code, but I did include \n after each input value

Comment: @mkrieger1 I will take a look at that module!

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the helpful comment concerning `flush()`. I am still learning how subprocess works

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure, I'm still trying to get `kill()` to run without crashing

Comment: @Harsha that worked, thank you! I am going to  read up on what '.wait()' is and how it functions

Comment: What Python version is this? Is this specifically Python 3.6? No combination of Python version and platform except 3.6 on Windows should produce this behavior and also support f-strings. If it *is* 3.6, see if you can upgrade - 3.6 is over 7 years old now.

Comment: On anything more recent, `close_fds` would default to `True`, and the subprocess wouldn't keep any files open. Unfortunately, before 3.7, `close_fds` cannot be set to `True` when IO redirection is used on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subprocess still had the file opened which is why `os.remove` did not have permission to remove the file.

Waiting for the subprocess to finish by using `output.wait()`<sup>1</sup> releases the file and allows it to be removed.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>suggested by [Harsha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12295445/harsha)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module?

You could replace;

```py
with open(student_txt_file, "w") as file:
```

With the following;

```py
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as file:
```

When the `with` context manager exits, it will automatically remove the file for you. It also chooses a suitable location (e.g. `/var/tmp`) and unique file name, so you won't need to calculate `student_txt_file`.